# Kubernetes: I can't get my cronjob to mount a PersistentVolumeClaim

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-pvc, kubernetes-cronjob

I am creating a Kubernetes cronjob that needs to write files, for that purpose, I have a server with the directory /data where the files shall be created.

My deployment is using Terraform.

My PersistentVolume:

```
resource "kubernetes_persistent_volume" "cronjob-demo-pv" {

  metadata {
    name = "cronjob-demo-pv"
  }

  spec {

    capacity = {
      storage = "490Gi"
    }
    access_modes = ["ReadWriteOnce"]
    storage_class_name = "standard"
    persistent_volume_source {
        host_path {
            type = "DirectoryOrCreate"
            path = "/data"
            }
    }

    node_affinity {
      required {
        node_selector_term {
          match_expressions {
            key      = "kubernetes.io/hostname"
            operator = "In"
            values   = ["<server-ip>"] # Replace <server-ip> for the IP of my server
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My PersistentVolumeClaim:

```
resource "kubernetes_persistent_volume_claim" "cronjob-demo-pvc" {
  metadata {
    name = "cronjob-demo-pvc"
    namespace = "testing"
  }
  spec {
    access_modes = ["ReadWriteOnce"]
    resources {
      requests = {
        storage = "490Gi"
      }
    }
    storage_class_name = "standard"
    volume_name = "${kubernetes_persistent_volume.cronjob-demo-pv.metadata.0.name}"
  }
}
```

My CronJob:

```
resource "kubernetes_cron_job" "demo" {
  metadata {
    name = "demo"
    namespace = "testing"
  }
  spec {
    concurrency_policy            = "Replace"
    failed_jobs_history_limit     = 5
    schedule                      = "* * * * *"
    successful_jobs_history_limit = 10
    job_template {
      metadata {}
      spec {
        backoff_limit              = 2
        template {

          metadata {}
          spec {
 
            volume {
                name = "cronjob-demo-pv"
                persistent_volume_claim {
                  claim_name = "${kubernetes_persistent_volume_claim.cronjob-demo-pvc.metadata.0.name}"
                }

            }
            container {
              name    = "hello"
              image   = "busybox"
              # command = ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo 'Hello World'"]
              # command = ["bin/sh", "-c", "touch /data/helloworld.txt; ls /data"]
              command = ["bin/sh", "-c", "ls; pwd"]
              volume_mount {
                    name = "mount-data-cronjob"
                    mount_path = "/data"    
                }
            }

          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I deploy this infrastructure, the command "ls" that I am running in the CronJob doesn't show my /data directory, which I need in order to write files.

What do I need to do to make my CronJob mount the volume /data successfully? Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

I tried using the "volume" and "volume_mount" in my CronJob definition, I don't know if there's something I am missing.

Comment: What does the resulting CronJob manifest look like? Does it run correctly? What is the final status of the pod?

Comment: As we don't know which terraform version you are using, it could be that the syntax is wrong. For example, `"${kubernetes_persistent_volume.cronjob-demo-pv.metadata.0.name}"` is the older syntax which should be replaced with `kubernetes_persistent_volume.cronjob-demo-pv.metadata.0.name`.

Comment: @MarkoE I am using Terraform v1.6.6 . Should I upgrade? is it too old?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you’ve shared, I have a couple of suggestions.

Ensure the names in the `volume` and `volume_mount` sections are identical to establish the correct mount.

```
volume_mounts = [
  {
    name       = "cronjob-demo-pv"
    mount_path = "/data"
  }
]
```

I’ll also advice you use the full path for shell commands and ensure the commands are correctly structured.

```
command = ["/bin/sh", "-c", "touch /data/helloworld.txt && ls /data"]
```

These changes should get your CronJob to mount the `/data` volume correctly and execute your command within that directory.

Comment: you were right! I changed the value of the volume_mounts's name to match the name of my PV and now my /data directory is showing fine. Thank you so much for the help! I hope this post helps future people who are working with cronjobs and PVs c: